# Python extract info from current line or next line

Tags: python

I'm trying to use python to parse some sql scripts to extract names of tables and columns affected by a given query.  The scripts have variations in format and some of them use this format:

```
Select col1, col2
FROM Table1
```

and other times it's like this:

```
 Select 
       col1, col2
    FROM 
       Table1
```

My code looks something like this:

```
tables1 = []
for line in file1:
   line2 = line.split()
   for i in xrange(len(line2)):
      if line2[i] = 'FROM':
         tables1.append(line2[i + 1])
```

Currently I'm parsing row by row but would need some kind of iterator to go to the next row if 'FROM' is the last string in the row. Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: just saying... http://sqlparse.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/

Comment: Since line breaks are apparently meaningless, parsing line by line is not a good idea. You'll have to analyse SQL syntax and determine the set of symbols that can terminate (or start) a certain construction. However using an existing parser would probably be better than going by mere intuition. If you really want to do it yourself: I believe SQL has an LL1 grammar, so a recursive descent  parser would be appropriate.

Comment: Can you just sanitize the sql before processing it? Strip all the new lines.

Comment: @Henrik: do you have an example - I can't find one in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

By using `re` module this problem will be solve easily :

```
import re

def parse_query(query):
    res = re.match('select\s+(?P<cols>.+)\s+from\s+(?P<tbl>.+)\s*;?', query, re.I|re.M)
    if res is not None:
        cols = [c.strip() for c in res.groupdict()['cols'].split(',')]
        return {'columns': cols, 'table': res.groupdict()['tbl']}

print parse_info_from_query('''Select col1, col2
                               FROM Table1''')

print parse_info_from_query('''Select 
                                   col1, col2
                               FROM 
                                    Table1''')
```

Comment: You will consider the new lines within your regex!

Comment: You need to replace `re.I` by `re.I|re.M` for multiline (in case the columns items are split), and replace the space separators by `\s*` to match any whitespace. You should add such whitespace to the start of the pattern too. `.+` for the table could be `\S+` to avoid trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

using sqlparse module.

go to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlparse, and download the tar.gz
and install:

```
> python setup.py install
```

then create the test file `sqlExamples.sql`:

```
Select col1, col2
FROM Table1;

 Select 
       col1, col2
    FROM 
        Table1
       ;
SELECT col3 FROM Table3;
```

then lets see if the parser can help us..
This is not very efficient script, it's written for learning:

```
import sqlparse

print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "loading the file into a string"
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
with open ("sqlExamples.sql", "r") as myfile:
    sql = myfile.read()
print sql

print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "Example 1: using the parser to reformat SQL to a standardized format"
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
formattedSQL = sqlparse.format(sql, reindent=True, keyword_case='upper')
print formattedSQL

print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "Example 1.A: reformatting statements, to single lines, for string analysis"
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
words = " ".join(formattedSQL.split()).replace('; ', ';\n')
print words

print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "Example 2: using the parser more directly, to extract coloumns"
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------------"
parsed = sqlparse.parse(sql)
coloumns = []
tables = []
for SQL in parsed:
    #For my test cases, the name of the statement and the affected table is the same thing..
    if( SQL.get_name() not in tables):
        tables.append( SQL.get_name() )

    #for debugging print token list:
    for token in SQL.tokens:
        if token.is_whitespace():
            continue
        if "SELECT" in SQL.get_type() and token.is_group():
            cols = token.value.split(",")
            for col in cols:
                if col.strip() not in coloumns:
                    coloumns.append(col.strip())
            break

print "tables:" + str(tables)    
print "cols:" + str(coloumns)
```